# JsonSyntaxException cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, json, android-emulator, gson

Hi everyone i am making an android application in which i was getting 4 error messages:

1. **GSON** cannot be resolved to a type
2. **JsonSyntaxException** cannot be resolved to a type

   and **2 more**

   I just added **gson-2.2.2.jar**, 3 errors has been resolved automatically,

   but still i am getting **JsonSyntaxException cannot be resolved to a type**

   I have tried many times to sort-out this issue, but did not get any way,
   now i need your help, please give some suggestions....

   Thanks

Comment: Last release of gson is `2.2.2` please upgrade.

Comment: Right Click > Properties > Java Build Path > Add External Jar [also updated to gson-2.2.2.jar]

Comment: @RC. Thanks and sorry it was my silly mistake.....but thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

Have you added `import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;` to the top of your code?

This kind of problem can quickly be resolved, in Eclipse, by pressing `Cmd-Shift-O` (OSX) or `Ctrl-Shift-O` (Windows/Linux)

Comment: Thanks and sorry it was my silly mistake.....but thanks for help....imports worked